# Prime checker including non primes

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I am trying to solve Project Euler number 7.

> By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
> What is the 10 001st prime number?

First thing that came into my mind was using length of list. This was very ineffective solution as it took over a minute. This is the used code.

```
def ch7():
    primes = []
    x = 2
    while len(primes) != 10001:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if x % i == 0:
                 break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
        x += 1
    
    print(primes[-1])

ch7()

 # Output is: 104743.
```

This works well but I wanted to reach faster solution. Therefore I did a bit of research and found out that in order to know if a number is a prime, we need to test whether it is divisible by any number up to its square root e.g. in order to know if 100 is a prime we dont need to divide it by every number up to 100, but only up to 10.

When I implemented this finding weird thing happened. The algorithm included some non primes. To be exact 66 of them. This is the adjusted code:

```
import math

primes = []
def ch7():
    x = 2
    while len(primes) != 10001:
        for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))):
            if x % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
        x += 1
    
    print(primes[-1])

ch7()

# Output is 104009
```

This solution takes under a second but it includes some non primes. I used math.ceil() in order to get int instead of float but I figured it should not be a problem since it still tests by every int up to square root of x.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: If x is a square, then math.sqrt(x) will be an integer, and math.ceil(math.sqrt(x)) will be that same integer. And range() doesn't include its last number.

Comment: But more importantly, using range() is way overkill -- you only need to check whether it is divisible by _primes_, and you have a list of primes right there.

Comment: For some reason when i added +1 to the range in order for the chceker to include the last number, it started working. Thanks very much

Comment: Have a look at the non-primes you got.  Are they numbers like 49 or 121, that are squares of primes?  If so then you had a boundary problem where you tested up to, but not including, the square root value.  That would explain why adding +1 to the range worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution generates a `list` of primes, but doens't use that `list` for anything but extracting the last element.  We can toss that `list`, and cut the time of the code in *half* by treating 2 as a special case, and only testing odd numbers:

```
def ch7(limit=10001):  # assume limit is >= 1
    prime = 2
    number = 3
    count = 1

    while count < limit:
        for divisor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
            if number % divisor == 0:
                break
        else:  # no break
            prime = number
            count += 1

        number += 2

    return prime

print(ch7())
```

But if you're going to collect a `list` of primes, you can use that `list` to get even more speed out of the program (about 10% for the test limits in use) by using those primes as divisors instead of odd numbers:

```
def ch7(limit=10001):  # assume limit is >= 1
    primes = [2]
    number = 3

    while len(primes) < limit:
        for prime in primes:
            if prime * prime > number:  # look no further
                primes.append(number)
                break

            if number % prime == 0:  # composite
                break
        else:  # may never be needed but prime gaps can be arbitrarily large
            primes.append(number)

        number += 2

    return primes[-1]


print(ch7())
```

BTW, your second solution, even with the `+ 1` fix you mention in the comments, comes up with one prime beyond the correct answer.  This is due to the way your code (mis)handles the prime 2.